# Microsoft Active Accessibility super sloooww when enumerating controls. Help!

Tags: winapi, accessibility

I am using active accessibility framework to enumerate all the controls for a given program. Problem is that when I traverse the tree of controls, it takes forever on complex applications like explorer or visual studio. Simple applications take about a second but large ones with lots of controls can take 10 seconds. Anyone experience this? I also found some references to using MSAA in process versus out of process. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, be careful when traversing recursively, because it sometimes happen that there are "cycles" in the "tree", and you cannot really compare objects reliably to see whether you have already been at this object...

The main reason why Active Accessibility is so slow, is that it is just not thought to be traversed recursively, but merely to show details about one single element (below cursor) or maybe its children. Every AA request (for every property) will have to switch context to the target application and back again. And, if you are doing the AA correctly (with lots of descriptions attached to all of your UI objects), there are simply a few thousand objects which will take time to traverse...

If you are looking for something specific, it might be easier to request that directly, instead of traversing all the controls. Or if you are only looking for some kinds of objects that only appear for HWNDs with other properties you know, it is a lot faster to first enumerate all the HWNDs and then call `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` on them (which does not only work for toplevel windows, but also for child windows). When enumerating their children, you can stop as soon as the HWND property changes.

And add some hard max counter for the recursion depth to avoid running into one of those cycles.

Comment: Can you provide some example. How you get a acc from an acc_path

Comment: I am confused what you mean by an acc_path. Googling suggests it is a concept used by AutoHotkey to encapsulate a hWnd and a list of child indices, but as I never used AutoHotkey, I think I cannot help you here. If you want to reimplement parsing of an acc_path in another language, you may want to try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-accessibleobjectfromwindow and then some https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-iaccessible-get_accchild to traverse the path.

Comment: bro your answer doesn't make any sense that's why I asked for more clarification. I'm looking for ACC element not HWND, I'm implementing this in c, and bump into the same problem as this dude. I know what element I want but it took 200ms to reach to it. some guy suggest `accNavigate` but still no example. `acc_path` is only a way of saying what element you want not bounded to AHK or any specific lang. You can get that with Inspect or Spy too

Comment: Sorry, I am still unsure what your problem is. You have found an inefficient way (while 200ms is still fast compared to things I was doing with Accessible objects) and want me to tell you how to make it more efficient without telling what your path looks like? My answer just suggests to navigate in the HWND space as fare as you can, and then switch to Accessible objects, and prune your scan of children as fast as you can. If you are already doing all of this and it is still "too slow", I probably cannot help you.

Comment: Thanks man, I heard UIA is the way to go and I'm trying that. I'm doing this for realtime app, 200ms is like a century in there

Comment: Good luck with that. I won't ask what you have to determine in real time where you have to rely on kludges like Active Accessibility :-) I've used it mostly for exporting data from applications that do not support usable export formats, and in this scenario 200ms do not matter - but 5 minutes instead of 15 seconds do.